# Native JDK code to copy files

Tags: java, file, streaming, copy, buffer

Is there a native JDK code to copy files(buffers, streams, or whatever)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "native" you mean "part of the Java standard API" (rather than platform-dependant code, which is usually called "native" in the Java world) and by "copy files" you mean "single method that takes a file and a target path and produces a copy of the file's contents" then no, there is no such method in the standard API. You have to open an `InputStream` and an `OutputStream` (optionally get their more efficient `FileChannel`s) and use a buffer to transfer bytes. Convenient single methods to call are found in [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).

**Update:** Since Java 7, file copy functionality has become part of the Standard API in `java.nio.file.Files`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but native in the Java world generally means platform dependent code...

Comment: nope, "native" in the java world mean its platform dependent code, aka the code is compiled and runs natively on the platform. While the standard API is platform independent and usually written in Java, that code will run as Byte Code in the JVM - in theory at least Byte Code is always the same no matter what platform you are in.

Comment: @Jon, KingInk: *I* know that - but it suspect Tom does not.

Comment: Thanks @Michael! I just copied to my code the commons-io method that copy Streams.

Comment: apache Commons IO is a bad choice, it doesn't use the NIO so it will be more CPU and memory intensive.

Comment: @Jarrod - Which library would you recommend that would use NIO?

Comment: @axiopisty: note that the question and answers are over 3 years old. Nowadays, you should use the `Files.copy` method that takes two `Path` parameters.

Answer (score 3):

This is the preferred way to copy a file since JDK 1.4 and later

```
public static void copyFile(final File sourceFile, final File destFile) throws IOException
{
    if (!destFile.exists())
    {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    try
    {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    finally
    {
       source.close();
       destination.close();
    }
}
```

[public abstract long transferFrom(ReadableByteChannel src,
                                  long position,
                                  long count)
                           throws IOException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long%29)

> ... This method is potentially much
>   more efficient than a simple loop that
>   reads from this channel and writes to
>   the target channel. Many operating
>   systems can transfer bytes directly
>   from the filesystem cache to the
>   target channel without actually
>   copying them. ...

Comment: Are you really sure you don't need a loop? transferFrom() returns "The number of bytes, possibly zero, that were actually transferred", just like InputStream.read()

Comment: @Michael: Nope, the `source.size()` designates the number of bytes which needs to be transferred. @fuzzy: in this example, `destination` won't be closed when `source.close()` throws `IOException`.

Comment: @BalusC Yeah, but the API doc explicitly says that the method may not, in fact, transfer that many bytes.

Comment: I have had the NIO file copy using channels running on Linux, Solaris and OSX in production environments for many years now and it has never failed to copy a file.

Comment: @Michael: I see. I'd rather stick to the 'good old' input/output loop.

Comment: @fuzzy: Translation: "it works on my machines". Never depend on behaviour that the API does not guarantee.

Comment: Agree with @Michael. But still thanks @fuzzy! I can use this adding the loop part.

Comment: The "loop part" is not needed and won't gain you anything. If it doesn't transfer the entire file looping won't do you any good. This method is not intended to be used in a loop. It is a "one shot" method, it either works or doesn't, which I have never had it fail.

Comment: search the internet, you won't find a single example of how to copy files using FileChannel that "loops" over transferTo/transferFrom. If they fail it is because the disk is full, the files get deleted out from under the code or some other catastrophic external event. "looping" over that is not what is intended nor useful and reduces the benefits of the methods as they are intended to be used.

Comment: point out where in the documentation it says to "loop" over transferFrom/transferTo, it says the exact OPPOSITE and I quoted that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to use Java NIO:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html

For buffers see:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html#buffers

For stream however, see the following article:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/file.html#readStream

There are frameworks built on top of this, namely Mina and Netty:

- Mina - http://mina.apache.org/
- Netty - http://www.jboss.org/netty

Comment: Thanks! And add to your list the Apache Commons IO, its very good!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that JDK7 defines several copy methods in java.nio.file.Files, including copying files and copy files to/from streams.